# Sudo still works despite removing my user from group

Tags: sudo, root

I just installed the April 4th 2022 edition of Rasberry Pi OS and added a root password in addition to my user password.  I also did..

```
deluser <userme> sudo
```

I tested my new security adjustment by using **apt** (without "sudo)" to install a package, and as I expected it wouldn't allow me (as regular user) to install the package, just as hoped. (I'm trying to tighten security, not disable security) Then I tested by prefixing "sudo" and to my surprise **apt** downloaded and installed my packages successfully, without even prompting for any password. I rechecked to see if I was listed in **sudo groups** and I wasn't.  So I rebooted and tried again.  **sudo** still worked without prompting for a password.

I researched and discovered I should edit the file `/etc/sudoers.d/010_pi-nopasswd` to force **sudo** to ask for a password, and now it does.
I edited the critical line to read `<user> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`
I also went into the Desktop Pi settings and selected to prompt for my user password and each bootup, and it does that.  So, the raspberry pi is asking for passwords,  but I'm trying to get rid of **sudo**

I want to switch to root powers using the **su** command to do things like installing new software with apt.  Currently, sudo still works just like before removing my user from the **sudo groups** with `deluser <userme> sudo`

Is that normal behavior for raspberry pi os to still use **sudo** even with my user removed from the **sudo group** ?  I suppose I'm misunderstanding something about **sudo**

Comment: Raspberry Pi OS is **Linux** and works the same as any other Linux OS. The only unusual aspect is that NOPASSWD is enabled by default, but this can be set/disabled on any OS.

Comment: is the ability to use sudo, despite having run "deluser <userme> sudo" the normal behavior?  I was expecting to not be able to use sudo in any form

Comment: Unless you understand sudo I recommend you don't fiddle with it. In particular DO NOT purge sudo. Debian assumes sudo (which is recommended practice and does not use root). You risk making your system unusable. You haven't explained what you attempt to achieve. By all means remove passwordless sudo if it makes you happy but don't imagine this improves security.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. I assume you issued your command to remove `userme` from the group `sudo` **as the root user?** It's OK not to be explicit about that, but if you're not going to be explicit, I think it's customary to show the `#` prompt to let us know you were root for this command; i.e. `# deluser <userme> sudo`. Are you sure `userme` was removed from the `sudo` group?

Comment: Actually I don't remember if I was root user or not when I issued the command # deluser userme sudo #   However, I'm doing a "groups userme" and "sudo" is not listed as a group that userme belongs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm following your explanation correctly, you issued the command `deluser <userme> sudo` as the `root` user. You also said, "I rechecked to see if I was listed in sudo groups", but you didn't say *how* you verified that.

I'll ***guess*** the reason that the `deluser` command you ran didn't get `userme` blocked from `sudo` access is rooted in the same issues addressed in [this Q&A from Ubuntu SE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828789/sudo-user-not-in-sudo-group). Here's some things to try/check:

- Verify `userme` is not listed as a member of the group sudo in `/etc/group`. If `deluser` works as we assume it does, your listing should **not** show `userme`.

  ```bash
  $ cat /etc/group | grep sudo
  sudo:x:27:pi
  ```

  ###### EDIT: Verified in comment
- If `userme` is still listed as a member of group `sudo`, then I would suggest that you create a new *regular* user, and then delete `userme` - in that order.

Again, this is guesswork, if you have a password login for user `root` then you won't be locked out.

###### EDIT:

I don't know what your `sudoers` file looks like, so I'll make another assumption that the following lines are in your sudoers file (open this using `sudo visudo`) :

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "@include" directives:
@includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

The first (uncommented) line beginning with `%sudo` is what allows any member of the `sudo` group to gain sudo privileges. If this line is in your sudoers file, **comment it out**; i.e.

```
# %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

And just for good measure, comment out the line that begins with `@includedir` - that line is what causes the scripts under `/etc/sudoers.d` to run.

As long as you have a `root` login, reboot your system, and now try to sudo from `userme`. If you do not get sudo, this "proves" that `userme's` membership in group `sudo` survived the `deluser` removal. I don't know *why* yet, but there's a reason - it's only software after all :)

Comment: I checked to see if *userme* was removed from *sudo* group by issuing the command **groups userme** and the command results didn't list *sudo* among the various other groups in the list.  I'm reading through the rest of your response just now.

Comment: I just checked the contents of */etc/groups* and the only entry for sudo reads **sudo:x:27:** (with no reference to userme) And, I grepped for *userme* and I'm listed in 15 groups but none with *sudo* in the line.  I'm still reading the rest of your post

Comment: The solution that I got to work was **#adduser newuser** it works as expected with *newuser* (it does not have sudo privileges, just as hoped)

Comment: I'm reading through your **EDIT** going to give that a try with **userme** which I have not removed yet

Comment: your new answer under **EDIT** also works!!  (I had already commented out the **%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL** using vim, but had not commented out **@includedir /etc/sudoers.d** at any rate, i went to check to see if I used the *visudo* utility correctly (and actually saved the file) by doing a *sudo cat/etc/sudoers* ..it asked for password, then said: * ...not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.*  that's what I was looking for! the problem has been solved for *userme* now!

Comment: @user12711: It's good to hear it's going your way, but I'm still puzzled why that membership in group `sudo` persisted. I've got a couple of theories, but I can't spend any more time on this at present. Just to share my thinking, I feel it has something to do with that first user (`userme`)... I'll guess again that the 2nd user can be dropped from sudo group with `deluser`, but that proof will have to wait - unless you've got the time & interest  :)

Comment: apparently my 2nduser (newuser) was never added to the sudo group.  using ** #groups newuser ** it just says the only group belonged to is the group by the identical name as the user.  And when try to use sudo with that second user, it reports back that its "...not in the sudoers file."  (unlike with userme, when originally I had that problem of sudo priveledge, my first user created during the installation of Rasberry Pi OS April 2022 version).   AND, that's the first time I remember their OS asking for user name and password.. in the past installations I had done it was always just user "pi"

Comment: @user12711: Yes - I vaguely recall that there are 2 commands for adding a user: `adduser`, and `useradd`  lol :) One of them "does it all" - creates a home directory, etc. So you may have used the other one??

Comment: I looked into that and used "adduser" which is the do it all command.  the *man adduser* says it actually uses useradd and sets everything up, there are options for setting up a regular user and an administrator.  I set it up as a regular user and it didn't add sudo to my group.  In fact, I only have one group assigned, the username. :-D

Comment: @user12711: That gives you several options then wrt `sudo`. Commenting out the `%sudo` effectively prevents any user from getting `sudo`, or put the `%sudo` line back in (remove the comment #) and utilize the 2nd user who does not belong to group sudo. And of course you can control the NOPASSWD option by directly editing the run-parts scripts under `/etc/sudoers.d`. The mind boggles  :)  The only remaining puzzle AFAIK is why all of our efforts to remove your original user from group `sudo` failed :/

Comment: @user12711: If you've still got your original `userme` account on your system, please check something: `sudo cat /etc/gshadow | grep sudo`. Is `userme` listed?

Comment: I still have userme, but since I successfully disabled userme from sudo use, from userme `sudo cat /etc/gshadow | grep sudo` after entering pw i get "...not in the sudoers file..." so, I'm doing `# cat /etc/gshadow | grep sudo` from su and get "sudo:*::"  Is that to be expected now?

Comment: @user12711: do it from your root account

Comment: no, userme is not listed with sudo from root. The response is # "sudo:*::"

Comment: @user12711: this has gotten a bit convoluted, and I'm concerned that you and I are out of sync wrt the configuration of your system now... I'm going to look into this further by removing pi from group `sudo` on one of my systems. I'll get around to this within the next week or so; got a couple of pressing tasks at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

There might still be an entry in the `/etc/sudoers` file.

If you don't want to use `sudo` I suggest you uninstall the package.

`apt purge sudo`

Comment: I'm just did a "sudo cat /etc/sudoers" and it lists: "root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL"  there is also another line that reads: "%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL"  - - - looks like all users are given root powers through sudo, regardless of membership with the sudo group???  and that the sudo group is commented out???  I will try reversing that and see what happens

Comment: actually, I shied away from commenting out the "root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" line because I was afraid I would lose all root power to do anything; I'm still trying to learn what that line does.  As for the "%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" that might not be a commented out line.  On second look the pound symbol is being used as a comment.  I did add a pound symbol to that line and the next time I used sudo it didn't ask for a password.  I need to learn about that file and will post again after I gain more knowledge

Comment: update, I commented out the line "%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL"  within the /etc/sudoers file.  *sudo* still works with *userme* and asks for my password... I'm getting closer to doing an "apt purge sudo" but still researching how to eliminate sudo privileges for *userme* without removing *sudo* altogether

Comment: @user12711: "`I commented out the line "%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" within the /etc/sudoers file. sudo still works with userme and asks for my password`"... ***Really!?!***

Comment: Yes sudo was still working with userme after commenting out that line using Vim.  I also used *cat* to double check the file to make sure the edit stuck, since that is read only file.  It did.  Problem solved now though using the advice in the other answer